# My Web Service Stub return null

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services

I have made a simple web service with eclipse. And i really don't understand why it is returning me null.

Here the Web Service server :

```
package server;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Set;

import entity.Book;

public class Library {
    private HashMap<String, Book> libraryHM = new HashMap<>();

    public Library() {

    }

    public Book add(String id, String name) {
        return  libraryHM.put(id, new Book(id, name));
    }

    public Book[] get(){
        Set<String> keys = libraryHM.keySet();

        Book[] bookArray = new Book[3];
        int i = 0;
        for(String key : keys) {

            bookArray[i++] = libraryHM.get(key);
        }

        return bookArray;
    }

}
```

The book class :

```
package entity;

public class Book {
    private String id;
    private String name;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Book(){

    }

    public Book(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return "Id: "+ id + ", name " + name; 
    }
}
```

And the client :

```
public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ServiceException, RemoteException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Library l = new LibraryServiceLocator().getLibrary();

        ((LibrarySoapBindingStub) l).setMaintainSession(true);

        l.add("1", "hello1");
        l.add("2", "hello2");
        l.add("3", "hello3");

        Book[] book = l.get();

        for(int i =0; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.println(book[i]);
        }
    }

}
```

To create the web service i do the following action :

new -> dyanmic web project -> write the library and book class.

Select library from the dynamic web project -> new -> web service -> select the 2 methods -> finish

And then the Web Service Client :
Selecting a new project -> web service client -> select the library wsdl -> finish

And when i run the main in client i have :

> nov. 09, 2016 7:45:45 PM org.apache.axis.utils.JavaUtils
>   isAttachmentSupported AVERTISSEMENT: Unable to find required classes
>   (javax.activation.DataHandler and javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart).
>   Attachment support is disabled.
>   null
>   null
>   null

Why ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to include the java mail and activation jars on your classpath.  You can google the class names and import them in your code.  The Eclipse IDE will do this for you automatically once you have the jars in place, press Ctrl + Shift + O

I know that at least this jar and possibly one other are required - You can download the mail jar [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-138643.html)

Comment: I don't anderstand i don't have any missing depedencies. WHat is it  ?

Comment: You clearly have missing dependencies as evidenced by your error.  The java mail API is a dependency and can be downloaded as a jar file.  Once that is done and you have included it on your classpath you can import the missing classes.

Comment: I will try your solution but i have this "AVERTISSEMENT" on other project but it's still working. DO you have any other idea ?

Comment: That just means "warning" in French.  Not sure why its in French, but if you solve your missing class file issue then this warning will go away.  You may need another framework as well which is the activation api - you will need to google and research which jar file is needed for that.

Comment: I added the two missing jars, the warning is now gone, but i still have a null pointer exception...

Comment: Set a breakpoint in your main class and start the program in debugging mode.  Step through the code and locate the line that throws the NPE

Comment: It's when i try to access the book[i] element. Because the l.get() above is returning me nothing.

Comment: Looks like you are using Spring there?  I am not familiar with this class called "Library" - I cannot find the documentation to it online but that looks like where you are running into trouble.  I try to avoid using spring at all cost because of its complexity.  This can be done using straight java.  You might want to consider a tutorial on java webservices using Java only.  Or go back and read your documentation on spring.  You can also update your question to focus specifically on the spring issue

Comment: I'm not using spring, Library is a class that contains books i created it. I followed a tutorial and i don't know where i failed.

Comment: can you post your LibraryServiceLocator class then?